# WordPress/PHP: Split a post up into different pages or not depending on source

Tags: php, wordpress

For those who might don't know, in WP we can split up a post by adding `<--nextpage-->` where we would like our page breaks to appear. This will create a pagination where each section has its own page.

What I want to do is, depending on the utm_source in the URL (ex: ?utm_source=fb) I want to have the pagination format to show, otherwise the one-page format will show.

Put simply, if the source is FB, the `<--nextpage-->` in my post will be executed, or if the source is not FB, `<--nextpage-->` won't execute.

I can do something with JS/JQuery if I only know how I can interact with the post content in the backend, not the end result that user can see. If it has to be done with PHP, I'm ready to learn to make it works. For those reasons I've no code to show for, but I've spent a lot of time looking for a solution with no success, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP determines & does the splitting of the content very early on.  I eventually managed to get it to work by adding a action to the loop start to strip the nextpage comments if the source was not FB.  \

Think carefully about whether you want to restrict this action from firing in any other situations, or restrict to only fire on certain posts.  At moment it is going to try strip the nextpage on every post.

```
function strip_next_tags_action () { 
    global $post;
         // put any other if conditions here
        if ( !isset( $_GET['utm_source'] )  or !($_GET['utm_source'] == 'fb')) {
            $post->post_content = str_replace("<!--nextpage-->", "",                
                                  $post->post_content, $count);
        }
        return $post;
    }
    add_action ('loop_start', 'strip_next_tags_action');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best done on the back end. You need to modify your `single.php` post template and use PHP code to display sections (or not) based on your query variables.

Over-simplified example:

```
<?php

get_header();

if( !isset( $_GET['utm_source'] ) ) $_GET['utm_source'] = '';

switch( $_GET['utm_source'] ){
    case 'fb':
        // do the Facebook stuff here
        the_excerpt();
        break;
    case 'something-else':
        // do the other stuff here
        the_excerpt();
        break;
    default:
        // if no matching utm_source variable, do this instead
        the_content();
}

get_footer();
```

Comment: Thank you, Patrick, for taking the time to help me, it's appreciated. As said in my initial post, my main concern is how to change things in the backend which your code doesn't address.  I want to know how to do the "do FB stuff" in your code. Thanks again.

Comment: See my edited question, I had some formatting issues so some information where missing